# why does recursion do this?

Tags: java, recursion

```
class Java_code {
public static void main(String args[]){

    mymethod(5);
}
static void  mymethod(int counter){
    if(counter==0){
    System.out.println("");
    }
    else {
    System.out.println("Hello" + counter);
    mymethod(--counter);
    System.out.println("" +counter);
    }
}
}
```

Suppose we have above program , when i give argument 5 it prints

```
Hello5

Hello4

Hello3

Hello2

Hello1
```

after that it prints

> 0
>
> 1
>
> 2
>
> 3
>
> 4

, but why does it prints numbers , how does it happen ? I don't understand how that happens can you help me out on this?

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21474297/trouble-understanding-recursion

Comment: There is a line `System.out.println("" +counter);` after the recursive function call `mymethod(--counter);` , this is exactly why it happens !

Comment: Paper and pen is also useful for small programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that these three lines will be executed as long as counter != 0

System.out.println("Hello" + counter);

mymethod(--counter);

System.out.println("" +counter);

mymethod() is being called initially with counter = 5. So it prints "Hello5" and before it returns, it calls itself recursively with the counter = 4 so prints "Hello4" and before it returns, it calls itself recursively with the counter = 3 so prints "Hello3" and before it returns, it calls itself recursively with the counter = 2 so prints "Hello2" and before it returns, it calls itself recursively with the counter = 1 so prints "Hello1" and before it returns, it calls itself recursively with the counter = 0 at which point it prints nothing but returns to the caller which will execute the rest of the code
System.out.println("" +counter) 
in each of the ongoing previous executions so on its' way back to the initial caller function it prints the values 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 respectfully.

Answer (score 0):

If you look carefully you can see this line

mymethod(--counter);

This is decreasing the value of `counter` and then passing it as a parameter to `mymethod`

This will be called for as long as counter > 0, then the method will return all the way up. 
After each method returns `System.out.println("" +counter);` will be executed.

The value of `counter` is being remembered in each call of `mymethod`

Answer (score 0):

```
  why does it prints numbers , how does it happen ? 
I don't understand how that happens can you help me out on this?
```

Because you have this line in your code

`mymethod(--counter);`-> recursive call so upto this line it continuously print (Hello world 1 to 5.)

After that only it executes this line

```
 System.out.println("" +counter);
```

This is called [stack buffer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_buffer_overflow)

Comment: I know that but what exactly happens in code when that line is executed ? how does it increment ?

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("" +counter);
```

prints those numbers. Because of `stack unwinding`  (whenever a method call happens the current state is pushed into the stack) And since stack is `LIFO (Last In first out)` so it is printing in the reverse order

Answer (score 0):

It will help you better understand what is happening if you draw the steps along with the current values of variables any time you use recursion because it can get confusing in the beginning until you get more familiar with it.